# OpenAI Chat Completions API: How do I use a function to store conversation memory?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I am trying to make a chatbot using OpenAI Function Calling. I have taken the basic example of getting the current weather condition, which was given in the documentation.

What I want to implement is to have a memory with it.

I tried to append into the message, but what I want is when I have a new message, so instead of calling the function, how can it get the response from memory if it's already asked?

My code is like this:

```
def get_current_weather(location, unit="fahrenheit"):
    print("IT RAN>>>>>>>>>>")
    weather_info = {
        "location": location,
        "temperature": "72",
        "unit": unit,
        "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"],
    }
    return json.dumps(weather_info)


messages = []


def run_conversation(input_message):
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": f"{input_message}"})
    functions = [
        {
            "name": "get_current_weather",
            "description": "Get the details about a drug/medication",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "definition": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA",
                    },
                    "unit": {"type": "string", "enum": ["celsius", "fahrenheit"]},
                },
                "required": ["location"],
            },
        }
    ]
    print("MESSAGE 1", messages)
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
        messages=messages,
        functions=functions,
        # function_call="auto",
    )
    response_message = response["choices"][0]["message"]
    print("RESPONSE MSG", response_message)

    if response_message.get("function_call"):
        available_functions = {"get_current_weather": get_current_weather}
        function_name = response_message["function_call"]["name"]
        function_to_call = available_functions[function_name]
        function_args = json.loads(response_message["function_call"]["arguments"])
        function_response = function_to_call(
            location=function_args.get("location"),
            unit=function_args.get("unit"),
        )

        # messages.append(response_message)
        messages.append(
            {"role": "function", "name": function_name, "content": function_response}
        )
        print("MESSAGE 2", messages)
        second_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
            messages=messages,
        )
        print("SECOND RESPONSE", second_response['choices'][0]['message'].to_dict())
        messages.append(second_response['choices'][0]['message'].to_dict())
        print("MESSAGE 3", messages)
        return second_response
```

It always runs the function even if I ask the same question

Output:

```
RESPONSE MSG {
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,
  "function_call": {
    "name": "get_current_weather",
    "arguments": "{\n  \"definition\": \"Boston, MA\",\n  \"unit\": \"celsius\"\n}"
  }
}
IT RAN>>>>>>>>>>
MESSAGE 2 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}]
SECOND RESPONSE {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Celsius.'}
MESSAGE 3 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}]
MESSAGE 1 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in NewYork?'}]
RESPONSE MSG {
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,
  "function_call": {
    "name": "get_current_weather",
    "arguments": "{\"location\": \"New York\"}"
  }
}
IT RAN>>>>>>>>>>
MESSAGE 2 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"locati
on": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}]
SECOND RESPONSE {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is 72 degrees. Please note that I did not specify the temperature unit, as i
t is missing in the response.'}
MESSAGE 3 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"locati
on": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is 72
 degrees. Please note that I did not specify the temperature unit, as it is missing in the response.'}]
MESSAGE 1 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"locati
on": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is 72
 degrees. Please note that I did not specify the temperature unit, as it is missing in the response.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperatu
re in Boston?'}]
RESPONSE MSG {
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,
  "function_call": {
    "name": "get_current_weather",
    "arguments": "{\"definition\": \"Boston\"}"
  }
}
IT RAN>>>>>>>>>>
MESSAGE 2 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"locati
MESSAGE 3 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degree
s Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"locati
on": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is 72
 degrees. Please note that I did not specify the temperature unit, as it is missing in the response.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'what is the temperatu
re in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location": null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny
", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees. Please note that the unit of temperature is missing in the resp
onse.'}]
MESSAGE 1 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}]
RESPONSE MSG {        
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,    
  "function_call": {
    "name": "get_current_weather",
    "arguments": "{\n  \"definition\": \"Boston, MA\"\n}"
  }
}
IT RAN>>>>>>>>>>
MESSAGE 2 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}]
SECOND RESPONSE {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Fahrenheit.'}
MESSAGE 3 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Fah
renheit.'}]
MESSAGE 1 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Fah
renheit.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in NewYork?'}]
RESPONSE MSG {
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,
  "function_call": {
    "name": "get_current_weather",
    "arguments": "{\"location\": \"New York\", \"unit\": \"celsius\"}"
  }
}
IT RAN>>>>>>>>>>
MESSAGE 2 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Fah
renheit.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location
": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}]
SECOND RESPONSE {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is 72 degrees Celsius.'}
MESSAGE 3 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Fah
renheit.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location
": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is
 72 degrees Celsius.'}]
MESSAGE 1 [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location":
 null, "temperature": "72", "unit": null, "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in Boston is 72 degrees Fah
renheit.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in NewYork?'}, {'role': 'function', 'name': 'get_current_weather', 'content': '{"location
": "New York", "temperature": "72", "unit": "celsius", "forecast": ["sunny", "windy"]}'}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The temperature in New York is
 72 degrees Celsius.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is the temperature in Boston?'}]
RESPONSE MSG {
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,
  "function_call": {
    "name": "get_current_weather",
    "arguments": "{\"location\": \"Boston\"}"
  }
is 72 degrees.'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using the OpenAI API function to store conversation memory is not the right approach because of the possibility that the model may generate invalid JSON or hallucinate parameters.**

People are already [having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76608259/openai-gpt-4-api-why-does-gpt-4-0613-hallucinate-make-up-function-parameters/) with that.

If you take a look at the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/function-calling), you can see that OpenAI transparently states:

> The basic sequence of steps for function calling is as follows:
>
> 1. Call the model with the user query and a set of functions defined in the functions parameter.
> 2. The model can choose to call a function; if so, the content will be a stringified JSON object adhering to your custom schema (**note: the
>    model may generate invalid JSON or hallucinate parameters**).
> 3. Parse the string into JSON in your code, and call your function with the provided arguments if they exist.
> 4. Call the model again by appending the function response as a new message, and let the model summarize the results back to the user.